# error: [Peer.js]: sendProposal - timed out after:120000

Tags: hyperledger

```
[root@localhost caliper]# node benchmark/simple/main.js 
info: [bench-flow.js]: ####### Caliper Test ######
info: [bench-flow.js]: Executing command: docker-compose -f network/fabric-v1.1/2org1peergoleveldb/docker-compose-tls.yaml up -d;sleep 3s
Creating network "2org1peergoleveldb_default" with the default driver
Creating orderer.example.com ... done
Creating ca.org1.example.com    ... done
Creating ca.org2.example.com    ... done
Creating peer0.org2.example.com ... done
Creating peer0.org1.example.com ... done
info: [create-channel.js]: Creating mychannel...
info: [create-channel.js]: Created mychannel successfully
info: [create-channel.js]: Sleeping 5s...
info: [join-channel.js]: Joining channels...
info: [join-channel.js]: Joining mychannel...
info: [join-channel.js]: Successfully joined peerOrg1's peers to mychannel
info: [join-channel.js]: Successfully joined peerOrg2's peers to mychannel
info: [join-channel.js]: Successfully joined mychannel
info: [install-chaincode.js]: Installing chaincodes...
info: [packager/Node.js]: packaging Node from /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/caliper/src/contract/fabric/marbles-norichquery/node
info: [packager/Node.js]: packaging Node from /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/caliper/src/contract/fabric/marbles-norichquery/node
info: [install-chaincode.js]: Installed chaincode marbles successfully in all peers
info: [packager/Node.js]: packaging Node from /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/caliper/src/contract/fabric/simple/node
info: [packager/Node.js]: packaging Node from /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/caliper/src/contract/fabric/simple/node
info: [install-chaincode.js]: Installed chaincode simple successfully in all peers
info: [instantiate-chaincode.js]: Instantiating chaincodes...
```

从这开始出错
    error: [Peer.js]: sendProposal - timed out after:120000
    error: [Peer.js]: sendProposal - timed out after:120000
    error: [client-utils.js]: sendPeersProposal - Promise is rejected: Error: REQUEST_TIMEOUT
        at Timeout._onTimeout (/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/caliper/node_modules/fabric-client/lib/Peer.js:124:19)
        at ontimeout (timers.js:482:11)
        at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:317:5)
        at Timer.listOnTimeout (timers.js:277:5)
    error: [client-utils.js]: sendPeersProposal - Promise is rejected: Error: REQUEST_TIMEOUT
        at Timeout._onTimeout (/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/caliper/node_modules/fabric-client/lib/Peer.js:124:19)
        at ontimeout (timers.js:482:11)
        at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:317:5)
        at Timer.listOnTimeout (timers.js:277:5)
    error: [instantiate-chaincode.js]: Failed to instantiate chaincodes: Error: Failed to send instantiate Proposal or receive valid response. Response null or status is not 200.
        at Object.instantiateChaincode (/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/caliper/src/fabric/e2eUtils.js:353:19)
        at 
        at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)
    error: [fabric.js]: Fabric chaincode install failed: Error: Failed to send instantiate Proposal or receive valid response. Response null or status is not 200.
        at Object.instantiateChaincode (/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/caliper/src/fabric/e2eUtils.js:353:19)
        at 
        at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)
    error: [bench-flow.js]: Error: Error: Failed to send instantiate Proposal or receive valid response. Response null or status is not 200.
        at Object.instantiateChaincode (/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/caliper/src/fabric/e2eUtils.js:353:19)
        at 
        at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)
    info: [demo.js]: [Transaction Info] - Submitted: 0 Succ: 0 Fail:0 Unfinished:0
    info: [bench-flow.js]: Executing command: docker-compose -f network/fabric-v1.1/2org1peergoleveldb/docker-compose-tls.yaml down;docker rm $(docker ps -aq);docker rmi $(docker images dev* -q)
    Stopping peer0.org1.example.com ... done
    Stopping peer0.org2.example.com ... done
    Stopping ca.org2.example.com    ... done
    Stopping orderer.example.com    ... done
    Stopping ca.org1.example.com    ... done
    Removing peer0.org1.example.com ... done
    Removing peer0.org2.example.com ... done
    Removing ca.org2.example.com    ... done
    Removing orderer.example.com    ... done
    Removing ca.org1.example.com    ... done
    Removing network 2org1peergoleveldb_default
    "docker rm" requires at least 1 argument.
    See 'docker rm --help'.

```
Usage:  docker rm [OPTIONS] CONTAINER [CONTAINER...]

Remove one or more containers
"docker rmi" requires at least 1 argument.
See 'docker rmi --help'.

Usage:  docker rmi [OPTIONS] IMAGE [IMAGE...]

Remove one or more images
error: [bench-flow.js]: Unsuccessful command execution. Error code: 1. Terminating signal: null
error: [benchmark/simple/main.js]: Error while executing the benchmark: Error: Command failed: docker-compose -f network/fabric-v1.1/2org1peergoleveldb/docker-compose-tls.yaml down;docker rm $(docker ps -aq);docker rmi $(docker images dev* -q)
Stopping peer0.org1.example.com ... done
Stopping peer0.org2.example.com ... done
Stopping ca.org2.example.com    ... done
Stopping orderer.example.com    ... done
Stopping ca.org1.example.com    ... done
Removing peer0.org1.example.com ... done
Removing peer0.org2.example.com ... done
Removing ca.org2.example.com    ... done
Removing orderer.example.com    ... done
Removing ca.org1.example.com    ... done
Removing network 2org1peergoleveldb_default
"docker rm" requires at least 1 argument.
See 'docker rm --help'.

Usage:  docker rm [OPTIONS] CONTAINER [CONTAINER...]

Remove one or more containers
"docker rmi" requires at least 1 argument.
See 'docker rmi --help'.

Usage:  docker rmi [OPTIONS] IMAGE [IMAGE...]

Remove one or more images

    at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:275:12)
    at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:214:7)
    at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:925:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:209:5)
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you are trying to test a network with Hyperledger caliper. try using this command-

```
node benchmark/simple/main.js -c yourconfig.json -n yournetwork.json
```

where after '-c' goes the config file of the benchmark and after '-n' goes the config file of the system under test.

for "simple" benchmark, (aforementioned the one you are using), it is config.yaml under benchmark/simple and you can find a bunch of smaple networks under /network folder.